How to get top 3 non-contract token holders for an ERC20 token
Context
I want to programmatically find the top 3 non-contract holders of a specific ERC20 token.
Example:
Input: 

    0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48

Expected Output:

    0x37305B1cD40574E4C5Ce33f8e8306Be057fD7341
    0x4B16c5dE96EB2117bBE5fd171E4d203624B014aa
    0x54edC2D90BBfE50526E333c7FfEaD3B0F22D39F0


Currently, I do this manually by visiting the Etherscan token holders page and copying the addresses of the top 3 non-contract holders.

Question
How can I automate this process? I.E. perform this operation programmatically?
Ideally, I’d like to use The Graph or a JSON-RPC API call, but I haven’t found any clear examples. The Etherscan Pro API offers similar functionality, but it’s too expensive ($200/month).
